# Why can't I download a file in iOS9

Tags: ios, ipad, ios9, epub

I have created a web page to download an epub file [download page here](http://www.sntruclear.com/epub) 
and it seems to work in my older ipad (running iOS8) but not on my newer ipad running iOS9 nor on my friends iphone (also iOS9) - I've googled around for anyone else having similar issues and there are no reported iOS9 bugs reported that are similar to my issue.

Things I have checked:

- checked file can download on PC using same internet connection
- checked mime types on server is set to application/epub+zip
- ensured wifi is connected so over-the-air download limit does not apply
- ensured that there is enough free space on the device (over 5gb free)
- checked popups are not blocked
- disabled icloud
- file works ok if you download onto PC then copy it onto iPads using iTunes

anyone got any other ideas?

Note, the button on the web page does a simple download time calculation using javascript, so the download indicator is only a visual clue that something is happening, it does not really measure download progress.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's an iOS 9 issue with file downloads in general in Safari. When you click download, Safari starts the download in the background without notifying the user. The user will only see the "Open in..." dialog when the download actually completes. This means that, since your ePub is pretty big, you're likely just not waiting long enough? I don't think there's a workaround. You'll likely just need to build in a warning of some sort.

Comment: It's not a matter of waiting. I have a 150mbps connection - the file downloads in less than 3 minutes on my pc over wifi. I left it running for a few hours just in case, and it didn't do anything. I think there must be a bug in ios that affects large downloads maybe